# How to edit the contents of a specific row in Python SQLite3 using ROWID

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

I have the following database (test.db):
[Test Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN8dw.jpg)

As seen in the picture,I created and populated a table ("stuffToPlot").

I want to edit a specific row (the 5th row for example), and change all the values therein.
I tried the following code to do this:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

tableToEdit = 'stuffToPlot'
rowToEdit = '5'
unixVar = 5.5
dateStampVar ='feb-2018'
keywordVar = 'Hello World'
valueVar = 25

c.execute("""INSERT INTO """+tableToEdit+""" (unix, datestamp, keyword, value)
VALUES (?,?,?,?) WHERE ROWID =""" +rowToEdit),(unixVar, dateStampVar, keywordVar, valueVar) 


conn.commit()

c.close()
conn.close()
```

I get the following error when trying to run the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Bob\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Python Test\SQLite3\SQLite3-3.py", line 19, in 
>       VALUES (?,?,?,?) WHERE ROWID =""" +rowToEdit),(unixVar, dateStampVar, keywordVar, valueVar)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

I have also tried using the UPDATE/SET method, but get a different error:

```
c.execute("""UPDATE """+tableToEdit+""" (unix, datestamp, keyword, value)
SET (?,?,?,?) WHERE ROWID =""" +rowToEdit),(unixVar, dateStampVar, keywordVar, valueVar)
```

> File "C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Python Test\SQLite3\SQLite3-3.py", line 24, in 
>       SET (?,?,?,?) WHERE ROWID =""" +rowToEdit),(unixVar, dateStampVar, keywordVar, valueVar)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

I just want to edit a specific row (using ROWID) ,any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT` always adds a *new* row, you can't use a `WHERE` clause when using `INSERT`. So yes, you have to use `UPDATE` here. Your `UPDATE` syntax is wrong however.

`UPDATE` uses `columname=value` pairs, see the [official documentation for `UPDATE`](https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html):

```
c.execute(
    """UPDATE {} SET unix=?, datestamp=?, keyword=?, value=?
       WHERE ROWID = ?""".format(tableToEdit),
    (unixVar, dateStampVar, keywordVar, valueVar, int(rowToEdit)))
```

I switched from using concatenation to `str.format()`, but only to put the table name in. The `ROWID` value can be passed in as a query parameter, so do so.

Demo:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('''
... CREATE TABLE stuffToPlot (unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value INTEGER)
... ''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10f049ce0>
>>> with conn:
...     for _ in range(10):
...         c = conn.execute('''
...             INSERT INTO stuffToPlot VALUES (42.0, "mar-2010", "The quick brown fox", 81)
...         ''')
...
>>> tableToEdit = 'stuffToPlot'
>>> rowToEdit = '5'
>>> unixVar = 5.5
>>> dateStampVar ='feb-2018'
>>> keywordVar = 'Hello World'
>>> valueVar = 25
>>> with conn:
...     conn.execute(
...         """UPDATE {} SET unix=?, datestamp=?, keyword=?, value=?
...            WHERE ROWID = ?""".format(tableToEdit),
...         (unixVar, dateStampVar, keywordVar, valueVar, int(rowToEdit)))
...
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10f049ce0>
>>> print(*conn.execute('SELECT * FROM stuffToPlot WHERE ROWID=5'))
(5.5, 'feb-2018', 'Hello World', 25)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes a lot of sense.